# unsigned char* C++ equivalent in C# (for raw data)

Tags: c#, c++, networking, packet

I'm translating some network code to C#.   There is a buffer in every packet with `unsigned char*` type. This is basically raw bytes of data.

Is using `string` appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array of [byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)s instead.